# How to implement magic functions in RubyOnRails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model that loads dynamically data from a REST API if a property is accessed and its property has no data:

```
class Issue
  attr_accessor :ticket_title, :priority, :description
  @ticket_title
  @priority
  @description

  def priority
    if !@priority.empty?
      updateProperties()
    end
    @priority
  end
  def description
    if !@description.empty?
      updateProperties()
    end
    @description
  end
  def ticket_title
    if !@ticket_title.empty?
      updateProperties()
    end
    @ticket_title
  end

  def updateProperties
    # loads all data from REST API
  end

  def initialize (hsh = {})
      hsh.each { |key, value|
        self.instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value) 
      }
  end

end
```

There are two problems:

1. If I initialize the model with `RedmineIssue.new :ticket_title => 'test'`, I dont want to the model to call `updateProperties`, but somehow it does.
2. Is there a way to declare functions magically? I.e., if there is no real function try to run a meta function?

Comment: What do you mean, "magically"?

Comment: I tried `Issue.new :ticket_title => 'test'` and it didn't call `updateProperties`. There's something else you're not showing.

Comment: If I understand what you mean by "magically", you need the `method_missing` hook. By the way, your initialize is potentially very insecure, and not terribly efficient. Replace using `instance_variable_set` with a hash.

Comment: @Linuxios: yeah, `method_missing` or `define_method`.

Comment: I added an answer with complete `method_missing` source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's something for the "magic". In your class, if you want to be able to get any part of a hash through a method named `get_whateverthekeyis` (silly example, I know), you'd use `method_missing`:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @h = {}
  end
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    if(name =~ /\Aget_(.+)\Z/)
      #Name is valid
      sig_class.class_exec($1) do |n|
        define_method("get_"+n) {@h[n]}
      end

      @h[$1]
    elsif(name =~ /\Aset_(.+)\Z/)
      #Name is valid
      sig_class.class_exec($1) do |n|
        define_method("set_"+n) {|v| @h[n]=v}
      end

      @h[$1] = args[0]
    else
      super
    end
  end
  private
  def sig_class
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end
```

When the method is not defined, it goes to `method_missing`. When that happens, `method_missing` does the requested operation on the hash, and then dynamically *defines* the method, so that next time it is a direct method call, meaning that it is much more efficient because the method already exists. This is somewhat akin the the `method_missing` used by Ruby's own OpenStruct.

Comment: Hi. Thank you and +1 for that. I will try the source next week and mark the answer as right after that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To dynamically add methods you should read about `method_missing`.
Good article explaining some of the aspects of it.
http://www.trottercashion.com/2011/02/08/rubys-define_method-method_missing-and-instance_eval.html

Comment: This is the proper way to address the issue as presented, but it seems like adding singletons outside the model would be a better way to approach the core of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the mean time I also found the method_missing hook... But thanks for the nice link and +1 for that! The answer of Linuxios is a bit more detailed, so I try its full source first...